# Top level function not running when export is called inside getStaticPaths()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, next.js, top-level-await

I am accessing a database from a Next.js SSG (static site generation) app. In order to prevent the app from having to reconnect to the db every time I make a query, I am exporting a global promise from one file and then calling it in a separate file (`controllers.js`) that contains multiple functions that directly query the db. Those functions are then called from within the `getStaticProps()` and `getStaticPaths()` methods in my actual components. Here is the code for `controllers.js`:

```
import clientPromise from "./clientPromise";

let client;
let db;

(async function () {
  // Await cannot be used outside of an async function (on the top level/module).
  // So we must call it below inside this async function that we immediately call instead of above where it is initialized.
  client = await clientPromise;
  db = client.db("dev"); // use development database
})();

// Query "technologies" collection:
export async function getTechnologies() {
  const technologies = await db
    .collection("technologies")
    .find({})
    .toArray();
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(technologies));
}

// Query "projects" collection:
export async function getProjects() {
  const projects = await db
  .collection("projects")
  .find({})
  .toArray();
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(projects));
}
```

And here is a snippet of where I am calling the my controllers:

```
// This works perfectly:
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const projects = await getProjects();

    return {
        props: { projects: projects },
    }
};

// This causes the error:
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const projects = await getProjects();

    return {
        paths: [{ params: {_id: "placeholder"} }],
        fallback: false,
    };
}
```

The error I'm getting is telling me that `db` is undefined and therefore I can't use the method "collection" on it. What I have concluded is that **my anonymous async function which should be calling itself immediately is not running when getProjects() is called within `getStaticPaths()` and therefore `db` is not being defined causing the error.** Everything works when I call getProjects() inside `getStaticProps()`, what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `db` is `undefined` at the time you call  `getProjects` then one of two things has happened:

1. You are just calling `getProjects` before `await clientPromise` has resolved
2. The resolved value of `clientPromise` is `undefined`.

You've not provided enough information to debug the second possibility, so let's assume the first is the problem here.

---

> ```
> (async function () {
>   // Await cannot be used outside of an async function (on the top level/module).
>   // So we must call it below inside this async function that we immediately call instead of above where it is initialized.
>   client = await clientPromise;
>   db = client.db("dev"); // use development database
> })();
> ```

You've got an `async` function here which returns a promise and you **could** use that promise to determine when the result was available.

Instead you've taken a fire-and-forget approach and are depending on a side effect that you can't control the timing of.

Take advantage of the fact it returns a promise.

```
const db = (async function () { 
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const devdb = client.db("dev");
    return devdb;
}();
```

Now `db` will be a promise that resolves to the value you want **immediately**  instead of being `undefined` and then changing later.

You'll need to change the rest of your module to account for that of course. For example:

> ```
> const projects = await db
>     .collection("projects")
> ```

will become

```
const devdb = await db;
const projects = devdb.collection("projects")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The code you suggested was similar to something I tried earlier, and both solutions work but are unfortunately very slow. However, due to your explanation I now understand that the slowness isn't coming from a programming error but rather a separate database issue.